# Find the cumulative sum from the previous number to the next

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of numbers:

```
x = [12, 8, 8, 6]
```

As you can see the first number is 12 so the sum of this and the next number which is 8 is 20. Next, the sum of 20 and 8 is 28, so on.

What I want as the final output is:

```
(12, 20), (20,28), (28, 34)
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
from itertools import chain
x = [12,8,8]
it = chain(x,[0])
result = list(x + next(it) for x in it)
print ('\n',result,'\n')
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Write some code for me” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: I did make an attempt to solve it in Jupyter Notebooks but wanted to be specific with the question so I just  posted it instead of posting my code. I did not know that posting my solution was a requirement so I made a mistake there but you are also wrong in assuming that I did not make an attempt.....

Comment: Again, refer to the posting guidelines.  If you do not show your applicable work, we assume that there is none.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: This is not pandas-related.

Comment: The reason we are so short with you is that this problem has about a 3-line solution.  When we don't see any code, we assume you didn't try anything.  Show us what you tried.

Comment: ok i took out pandas and wrote the code that I was trying

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a comprehension using assignment expresion to remember the last number:

```
last_num = x[0]
output = [(last_num, last_num:= last_num+i) for i in x[1:]]
```

---

```
[(12, 20), (20, 28), (28, 34)]
```

Roughly equivilent to:

```
last_num = x[0]
output = []
for i in x[1:]:
    output.append((last_num, last_num + i))
    last_num += i
```

Or if you're ok with importing `itertools` you can use `acumulate`:

```
print(*accumulate(x))
12 20 28 34
```

And with `zip` and `itertools.tee`:

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee

a, b = tee(accumulate(x))
next(b, None)
output = list(zip(a, b))
```

---

```
[(12, 20), (20, 28), (28, 34)]
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much!!!! Just one question, in the output can the square brackets be removed?

Comment: Got it!! I removed the brackets using: new = str(output)[1:-1]

Comment: why not just `print(*output, sep=',')`

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tried it with `itertools`, so here's one more solution:

```
from itertools import accumulate, tee

i1, i2 = tee(accumulate(x))
next(i2)
print([*zip(i1, i2)])
```

Prints:

```
[(12, 20), (20, 28), (28, 34)]
```